# Grey box does not follow

Tags: html, css

I've added a grey box to my site. i want the box to follow the bottom of my page as more pictures are uploaded to my site. How do I make that work.

```css
.GreyBG {
        background: #595959;
        position: absolute;
        border-style: solid;
        width: 50%;
        //578px;
        height: 70%;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        top: 220px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #21262c;
        border-radius: 1px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        z-index: -1;
        }
```

```html
<div class="GreyBG"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `top:220px` to `bottom :0;`
This will stick the div to bottom of the page.

> Update

Change the css to this:

```
.GreyBG {
    background: #595959;
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 50%;
    //578px;
    height: 70%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    top: 220px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #21262c;
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.GreyBG img {
    width: initial;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: This will not work if you have another div with `position: relative` in your code. [Look here](https://jsfiddle.net/zq7Lqx5h/)

Comment: @MarcusLönnqvist : You want the grey box to be at the bottom. Thats what is in your question. What is it that you need exactly?

Comment: @AbhayNaik : I want the bottom of the box to follow the bottom of the page as i scroll down. There are uploaded pictures inside the box, and when there are too many photos uploaded they go outside the box on the bottom.

Comment: @MarcusLönnqvist : Updated the answer .Please check if that is what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the parent element and its display parameters, but in general just remove `position: absolute;`, which will make it static and scroll with the rest.

Comment: This solution made the whole box go away

Comment: most likely because of your setting `height: 70%;`: If the parent container does not have a height definition, those 70% are 70% of nothing = 0px. I'd have to know the context to be able to say more. If there is really nothing else in between that and `body`, try to add `height: 100%` to the `body` element

Comment: addition: or just give it a height value in pixels - that's independent of any other circumstances